# Implementing Jade with Node.js and mysql table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, pug

I am attempting to take items on my 'users' table and format them into a table using Jade to display for my web app. I am unsure on how to send information from 'users' to Jade in order to create the list and I am unsure about the corresponding code necessary to implement the table using Jade. Below is my code so far in Node.js. Any advice is appreciated!

```
var pub = __dirname;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(pub,'public')));


var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(express.static('static_files'));

var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
 host: 'localhost',
 port:'3306',
 user: 'root',
 password: '9696',
 database: 'users'
 });



app.get('/list', function(req, res){
pool.getConnection(function(err,con){
con.query('SELECT * FROM user set' , function(err, results){
if (err) {
  throw err;
}
res.render('username', {
  title: results[0].title,
  results: results
});
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1** - How to pass variables to the jade processor (you did this correctly):

```
  res.render('username', {
      title: results[0].title,
      results: results
  });
```

**Part 2** - How to use the variables in the jade page:

First of all, remember that you are passing a single variable object to the jade processor that contains all the variable you will use. However, the properties are referred to by simply calling them (so `title === results[0].title`).

Jade has 2 formats for inserting variables depending on the situation:

1. The regular method of:

   ```
     title  My Website | #{title} // #{nameOfPropertyOfPassedVariableObject}
   ```
2. When dealing with quotes such as `li a(href="/myusers/#{user.email}")`, you have to do it slightly differently:

   ```
     li a(href="/myusers/"+user.email) // +nameofpropertyofpassedvariableobject
   ```

   with no `#{}` but with a `+` and also **the variable must be outside the quotes**.

   This is just one of the funky things with jade.

Let me know if you also want to know about loops and stuff. Also, here are 2 excellent resources for jade (these are how I started):

- A random website I found: http://webapplog.com/jade/
- Official Documentation: http://jadelang.com/tutorial/

Comment: If I answered your question, please accept and mark the answer as correct. If not, please let me know what did not work.